# Getting null from FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext() while making mock object

Tags: jsf, object, mocking

I am new to JSF, I am getting a NullPointerException when I am trying to call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext() from my code. 
I am working on testing some module built on jsf, so I build a mock object of FacesContext using myfaces. 
My code looks like-

facesContext=new MockFacesContext20(); 
System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext());

Please help me with some example...! 
Is there a way to initialize a mock FacesContext object with custom PartialViewContext??

Answer (score 0):

FacesContext is a singleton, and thus doesn't lend itself well to most mocking frameworks.

The Apache Shale project aimed to resolve this issue, however it was retired years ago:

http://shale.apache.org/

Even though it is no longer being supported, I have used it with relative success in my projects, however my general recommendation is to keep business logic out of the ManagedBean.  I like to keep unit tested business logic within my business logic layer, while my managed beans act like a wrapper, retrieving parameters and information from FacesContext and passing it as arguments to business logic method calls.

It lends itself better to TDD without worrying about using software from a retired project.

Comment: I just want to get the PartialViewContext so that I can test my application..I have already implemented myfaces test framework. Is it posiible with shale that I wont get NPE??

Comment: I am not sure about PartialViewContext, but everything else I tried under FacesContext with Shale worked perfectly fine.  It is worth a try.

Comment: @RahulDhiman I am happy that you solve this, but please provide the solution as an answer to your own question.  Nothing makes me more angry than searching for my problem online and reading "Problem solved" with no solution.